# How to print the given ZIG ZAG pattern using C?

Tags: c

[image: Zig Zag Pattern]

I'm scratching my head from the morning and I didn't even reach something which looks like given pattern. Any amount of help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

**This is not my home work**

EDIT 1: Thank You all! I finally arrived at the solution.

```
`#include<stdio.h>

  void main(){
     int n,i,count;
     scanf("%d",&n);
     int prev=n,next=(n*2)+(n-2),tc=1;
     for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if(i==1) {
                for(count=1;count<=(n*2)+(n-2);count++)  {
                    if(count==prev || count==next) printf("*");
                    else printf(" ");  
                }
            }
            else  {
                for(count=1;count<=2*n*n;count++){
                    if(count==prev-tc || count==prev+tc ||   count==next-tc|| count==next+tc) 
                           printf("*");
                    else printf(" ");
                }
           tc++;
          }
     printf("\n");
     }
  }`
```

Comment: So where is your code? Can't really help without a [mcve] and a specific question about it.

Comment: Start with a pen and some papers, and think a little and try to get it right there first.

Comment: Start by solving just the first star in each row.

Comment: Use nested loops, outer loop for number of rows to be printed and inner loop for each row. use if-else for spaces and star. When you able to print something post it, then we will help you again

Comment: tell what you have been reached so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve questions of this type you must find a formula for spaces and a formula for stars. these formulas tell the computer how many spaces and stars must be printed in **each line.**
that's all these types of questions need.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){ 

    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int x=n;x>=i;x--){
            printf(" ");
        }


        int y=2*i; int f=1;
        while(y!=1){
            if(f!=1&&f!=2*i-1){
                 printf(" ");
            }
            else if(i==n&&f==2*i-1){
                 printf("");
            }
            else{
                printf("*");
            }
            f++;
            y--;



        }
       if(i==n){
           printf("*");
       }
        for(int xk=n;xk>i;xk--){
            printf("  ");
        }

          int y1=2*i; int f2=1;
        while(y1!=1){
            if(f2==2*i-1){
                 printf("");
            }
            if(f2!=1&&f2!=2*i-1){
                 printf(" ");
            }
            else if(i==n&&f2==1){
                 printf(" ");
            }
            else{
                printf("*");
            }
            f2++;
            y1--;



        }


        printf("\n");
    }



}
```

Comment: This might be helpful.